# Zend Framework 2 and zftool in PHPStorm Command Line

Tags: php, command-line, zend-framework2, phpstorm

I've got problems with **integration zftool into PHPStorm**. I tryied it in two ways:

- by composer and setting absolute path in `Command Line Tool Support` to zf.php
- by downloading and setting absolute path in `Command Line Tool Support` to zf.phar

For example I've added composer into `PHPStorm Command Line Tool Support` with writing path `$PhpExecutable$ composer.phar`.

Look [there](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/integrating-composer-command-line-tool-with-phpstorm/)

I tried to do the same with ZFTool but it didn't work for me.:

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0zftool.phar" %*>zftool.bat
```

And then in PHPStorm `$PhpExcecutable$ zftool.phar`, and add to global variables folder `zftool/bin`

My questions are:

1. How to set it up in PHPStorm Command Line?
2. What exacly `$PhpExcecutable$` is and can I set/install any .phar like this? (I've
   chose automatic installation of composer).

Comment: *"What exacly $PhpExcecutable$"* -- it's what you set up in `Settings | PHP | PHP Interpreter`

Comment: *$PhpExecutable$ composer.phar* -- in this case the `composer.phar` has to be in your project root folder; if such phar file is located elsewhere then full path to it should be provided.

Comment: On related note: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Composer+Support+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've got it. I forgot that I've created project by composer, and in main project path I've got composer.phar file. So I put zftool.phar into main folder and everything works fine. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed this issue:

1. Downloaded a zip ball from [zend web site](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/zipball/master)
2. Extracted it under the `vendor` directory with `ZFTool` name (I guess case is important)
3. Downloaded phar from [here](https://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar) and placed in the same `ZFTool` directory
4. Added a new record to the `Command Line Support` in PhpStorm and pointed to the `phar` file.

Easy? Don't think so :S

Comment: This method works only when create a new 'zendframework/skeleton' project from composer, for some reason I see an error when try to do the same things for already created project...